# Running commands using root in a loop

Tags: linux, terminal

I`m following along this post :

https://vpsboard.com/topic/4095-ipsecl2tp-vpn-on-ubuntu-1404/

in order to setup VPN Server in Ubunto, however when i come to this command :

```
for vpn in /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/*; do echo 0 > $vpn/accept_redirects; echo 0 &gt; $vpn/send_redirects; done
```

I get Permission Denied, also i`m running the command using sudo!

i know sudo doesnt work with redirects but i dont know how to rewrite this command in order to execute it using su -c

Comment: First thing: Replace `&gt;` with `>`. That's an HTML issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run it as root after by

```
 sudo su -
 for vpn in /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/*; do echo 0 > $vpn/accept_redirects; echo 0 > $vpn/send_redirects; done
```

or with sudo as

```
sudo /bin/bash -c "for vpn in /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/*; do echo 0 > $vpn/accept_redirects; echo 0 > $vpn/send_redirects; done"
```

Comment: still gives me /bin/bash: /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/lo/send_redirects: Permission denied

Comment: also it gives me gt: error: neither tool nor script specified; option -help lists possible tools

Comment: Be careful. The command is crap because the author of the original post didn't noticed that `>` got replaced by the HTML  `&gt;`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sudo bash -c`  to make it work:

```
 for vpn in /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/*; do 
   sudo bash -c 'echo 0 > $vpn/accept_redirects; echo 0 > $vpn/send_redirects'
  done
```